# user, role, permissions and a specific group RBAC?

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to design a database schema for a project using mysql as the database. and i am stuck on the authorization part, the business rules are as follows:

1. a role can have many permissions, and a permission and can be inserted in many roles
2. a user can have many roles, and one role can be assigned to many users
3. now this is the part that can't get it right, Every user can be in many "groups" but in each he can be assigned only to one role (by groups i mean group of people and not group of roles)

the following picture is what i came up with till now, what should be amended? 
[image]

Comment: Can a user be assigned to a role without going "through" a group?  Ex. group administrators == role administrator.  Can a user have role administrator without being in group administrators?  If the user has to be in the group that corresponds to the role, link group to 1 role, and add a group_has_user table.  Delete role_has_user.

Comment: @Nic3500, No, a user must have a role but not necessarily a group. so an admin will have a role admin but there will be no group for admins.

Comment: @Pomanh Group permissions what about this part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your question and answer to my comment, here is the model I came up with:

[image]

This meets your requirements.  The main difference with your model is how the groups are setup.

- Group has a 1:1 relation with Role, which can be null (i.e. a group can exist even it no role is associated to it).
- In each Group, you have a foreign key to the Role table.
- If you need to know the roles a users has: individual roles through User_has_Role + role attached to each group the user is a member of (through Group_has_User).

Comment: this is actually an interesting answer, however, while I accept the explanation, the layout is not in sync with it. i mean you said that a 1 group has many roles which i agree with, but the diagram shows the opposite (i.e. 1 role has many groups) ... also there should be the possibility to have the foreign group key to be null, amend that in the diagram and i will accept your answer

Comment: Modifications made.

Comment: why change to a 1:1 relation? i think there is something wrong with it. it is as if you are saying that each group if exists can have only one role (my initial request was each user has a role in a group), so according to the your proposal I expect the following Role(id, name, group_id =>nullable) and Group (id, name) with a relation Group(0):Role(N)

Comment: Your initial post says "Every user can be in many "groups" but in each he can be assigned only to one role".  That is why I understood one group == one role.  But at this point, you are welcome to adjust as required for your real life project.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a table for each group which contains user and effective role(as user in one group can have only one role). There is also one implementation specific flaw, if user can be in multiple groups and in one group he can have only one role, so there must be some provision to decide effective group for the user which is going to decide effective role for user.
If users relationship with the group is only factor that decides the role user can have, then there is no point of having direct relationship between user and role.

Comment: for your first point, a table for each group: this will be not applicable as groups can increase unexpectedly. for the third point, a group means a role situation: this is not the case here. lastly i can't understand what is the implementation flaw, can you give an example for the correct implementation as you see it.